# File Server Solution for small business

Tags: backup, linux

I need a simple file management solution for the following small business setup: an Ubuntu Hardy Linux Server and Windows and Mac OS X Clients.

We want to store and manage max 10 GB of files including documents, images, a few videos etc.

Our needs:
- store all documents safely on the linux server (it is backed up daily)
- be able to copy the whole documents to the local disks and work there (because computers go often offline) and check in those changes later on.
- browse and download files from a web browser
- auto sync document folders to and from server (how to handle conflicts,folder renames, file deletions???)

I have been thinking of:

- A version control tool like SVN/GIT or similar
- rsync
- bacula

However I would definitely want to hear some expert opinion. Any hints is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you work mostly with text files and have technically sophisticated users, a VCS like git or SVN is fantastic.

KnowledgeTree has been a fantastic solution for us for our non-IT user base. We used the Community Edition for several years(Even ISO 9001 certified on it) before upgrading to the commercial version.

I did do some research on some file server alternativesto our KnowledgeTree implementation about a year ago. Several Plone based systems came out as strong alternatives because they supported both WebDAV based drag and drop and version control

Answer (score 0):

SVN/Git will get you your version control and offline abilities: when you check out a file, you'll have a copy of it.

You can use the mod_dav_svn module along with Apache to server SVN files through Apache; this will allow you to "browse and download files from a web browser".  There's also [USVN](http://www.usvn.info/) which uses PHP and also allows you to create and modify your repos from a browser.

Depending on how you want to back it up (are you using tape, an external harddrive, online), there's alot of options, Bacula being one of them.

I don't think you need `rsync` as long as your users check their files in regularly at the end of the day, if that's what you were implying with having `rsync` in your list.  I originally was thinking of Windows built-in Offline Files feature, but apparently there isn't a Mac equivalent, at least not part of the OS (there may be some 3rd-party stuff out there).

Answer (score 0):

If your staff are technical and aren't afraid of svn, I would say that that is the way to go.

On the other hand, have you considered a CMS?  (Searching for "Open Source CMS" should get you plenty of options.)

-Waldo

Answer (score 0):

- Version control. TortoiseSVN (and Tortoise* for other VCS) integrate with Windows Explorer
- You might try to enable offline folders and have it work with Samba
- Unison
- There are numerous tools to visualize VCS repositories on the web, such as ViewSVN